# Trying to stringify textbox input data and uploaded images in json format to send through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to stringify textbox input data and  uploaded images in json format to send through ajax.but getting error at `alert(file[0].name + " is not a valid image file.");`
and at this point in ajax part  `data: '{user: "' + JSON.stringify(user) + '",byteData: "' + byteData + '", imageName: "' + fileName + '", contentType: "' + contentType + '" }',`

Given below is the script which is accepting value from textboxes, labels and image upload control and then stringify all the values and passing it through Ajax in json Format.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vwggn.png)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/json2/0.1/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var fileName;
        var contentType;
        $("#pdfForm").on('change', 'input[name=flImage]', function () {
            alert('Thanks for selecting image');
            if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.jpg|.jpeg|.gif|.png|.bmp)$/;
                $($(this)[0].files).each(function () {
                    var file = $(this);
                    if (regex.test(file[0].name.toLowerCase())) {
                        fileName = file[0].name;
                        contentType = file[0].type;
                        reader.readAsDataURL(file[0]);
                    } else {
                        alert(file[0].name + " is not a valid image file.");
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alert("This browser does not support HTML5 FileReader.");
            }
        });
        $(document).on("click", "[id*=btnFrmSubmit]", function () {
            alert("hi");
            var user = {};
            user.PRODUCT_ID = 1;
            user.TDC_NO = $("[id*=Tdc_No]").val();
            user.REVISION = $("#Revision").text();
            user.REVISION_DATE = $("[id*=Revision_Date]").text();
            user.P_GROUP = $("[id*=P_Group]").val();
            user.PROD_DESC = $("[id*=Prod_Desc]").val();
            user.N_I_PRD_STD = $("[id*=N_I_Prd_Std]").val();
            user.APPLN = $("[id*=Appln]").val();
            user.FRM_SUPP = $("[id*=Frm_Supp]").val();
            user.CREATED_DATE = $("#Revision_Date").text();
            user.CREATED_BY = $("[id*=lblUserName]").text();
            var byteData = reader.result;
            console.log(byteData);
            byteData = byteData.split(';')[1].replace("base64,", "");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "TDC.aspx/SaveFrmDetails",
                data: '{user: "' + JSON.stringify(user) + '",byteData: "' + byteData + '", imageName: "' + fileName + '", contentType: "' + contentType + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("User has been added successfully.");
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what error? Could you add fiddle? data: is allowed to be a js PlainObject, why you try to represent it as a string?

Comment: @Constantine i updated the issue with image .Please have a look on it.

Answer (score 1):

For ajax file upload, it is better to use Formdata refer the link below

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Hope this helps. Please feel free to ask for any clarifications

Comment: Could you guide how exactly i should use formadata ..actually article doesn't clear doubt..